# mongodb get data from another collection inside a query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

> product collection sample data

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "title" : "A Product",
    "seller": "444",
}
```

> seller collection sample data

```
  {
  "_id" : "444",
  "title" : "Salesman B",
  }
```

> intended data (when the query to product collection)

```
  {
    "_id" : "123",
    "title" : "A Product",
    "seller": "Salesman B",
}
```

> Let say i have 2 collection (product and seller) can i have the result of intended data example in one query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $lookup command. There is a comprehensive MongoDB document (link below) that explains how this works, which is equivalent to JOIN command in SQL.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

$lookup did the trick, after that i added $unwind and $replaceRoot for customize the output data, thanks.